# Multiple Magento SUPPEE Patches Not Installing

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I am having issues applying patches to my Magento store, below I have included the current installed patches and a link to each log of the failing patches. I am unsure why half of these patches installed and the other half did not.

Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

**Installed Patches:**

- SUPEE-9652
- SUPEE-9767
- SUPEE-10570
- SUPEE-10975

**Patches Failing To Install:**

- PATCH 10888: https://hastebin.com/misoxonede.cpp
- PATCH 10752:https://hastebin.com/uxuqonodar.makefile
- PATCH 8788: https://hastebin.com/eqixagurur.cpp
- PATCH 5344: https://hastebin.com/lekitipafo.makefile

Comment: maybe the possibility someone installed manually. so check one file manually.

Comment: After few thrillers with Magento Patches, we've end up copying new Magento files over the old ones.

Comment: I have had to revert all patches before, just to get to supee-3941 and make sure that was installed correctly. Then patch each one in order.